# How to set maximum velocity of a rigidbody in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Nothing seems to work, played around for a few hours, copied and pasted 'solutions' from google but nope.
Changing the maxSpeed variable doesn't do anything. Object still flies across the screen like Barry Allen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{

    [Range (0, 5)]public int speed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    public Vector3 veloc;
    public float maxSpeed;

    void Start () 
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        speed = 4;
        maxSpeed = 0.01f;
        veloc = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (Vector3.up * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (-Vector3.up * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (Vector3.right * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (-Vector3.right * speed);
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if(veloc.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2D.velocity = rb2D.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing seems to work", have you tried debugging your code? Do it step by step and you'll understand it better

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto 
Yup I did debug the code. There were some errors in the beginning but I've fixed them. There are no errors in this build, just the velocity keeps on increasing.

Comment: Does it enter into the if of `FixedUpdate`? What's the value of `rb2D.velocity.normalized`? What's the value of `maxSpeed`?

Comment: Okay, I got it. The `veloc.magnitude` value was only read in the Start method, so it was always at 0. Instead I changed it to `rb2D.velocity.magnitude` for it to continually update as the object moves throughout the screen.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. You should post that as an answer, with better format and the resulting code :)

Answer (score 5):

only this:

```
void Update() {
rb2D.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb2D.velocity, maxSpeed);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

I need to sleep more. Just change veloc.magnitude to rb2D.velocity.magnitude in the FixedUpdate method if you had a similar problem. The object does 'stutter' upon reaching max velocity but I am yet to find a solution to that.

```
 void Start () 
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        speed = 4;
        maxSpeed = 0.01f;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (Vector3.up * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (-Vector3.up * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (Vector3.right * speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb2D.AddForce (-Vector3.right * speed);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if(rb2D.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2D.velocity = rb2D.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```