# Script doesn't limit the fall speed of objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Script should limit objects fall speed.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float verSpeedLimit = 0;
    void Start() => rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    void Update() => rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -verSpeedLimit, Mathf.Infinity), rb.velocity.z);
}
```

I am newfag of coding and I write little script which should limit objects fall speed, but I realize that speed higher then my limit (variable), mb sb can help me?

Comment: this may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122532/how-to-set-maximum-velocity-of-a-rigidbody-in-unity

Comment: @nkazz
yep i do something like this already

        Vector3 HorVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

        if (HorVel.magnitude > MoveSpeed)
        {
            Vector3 limitedHorVel = HorVel.normalized * MoveSpeed;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedHorVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedHorVel.z);
        }

 but i need only vertical down limiter (Fall speed limiter), i try to make like flying using this

Comment: i also test this with:
`void Update() => rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);`
all same

Comment: Did you *double-check* if the parameters of the `Clamp()` method are correct?

Comment: yes, all are correct

Comment: but it seems like you clamp between the current speed and -maxspeed and your input is the highest possible float.
so  if you want to clamp at 200 but your current speed is 205 you clamp between 205 and -maxspeed,

Comment: it really doesn't want to work...

Comment: @nkazz with clamp all ok, like i say higher i use `0f` instead of `Clamp()` but everything same

Comment: idk mb my unity ver work cursed, i use unity 2021.3, with unity version control and unity cloud, to check i can try to create new empty project instead of my game project.

Comment: yep about clamp, i use range from min = -VelLimiter (fall speed) and max = inf, oh and value is my start speed that i change on clamped.
`public static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max);`

Comment: How did you realize that?

Comment: @shingo, emm... just read [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)...

Comment: @shingo oh, or you about that it doesn't work?

Comment: I meant how you realized that the speed is higher than your limit. By observation or measurement?

Comment: @shingo if about that it doesn't work, i just test in unity

Comment: @shingo em, i set it on 0 but cube moves

Comment: oh, and also i have speedometer script

Comment: hah, mb i should turn off gravity and write my own?

Comment: 1. You shouldn't change velocity in Update, because [physics updates in FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html). 2 [In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html), use AddForce instead.

Comment: oh, in this case i should use `if` and in my case it almost work if i use
`void Update() => rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0.2f, rb.velocity.z);`
instead of 
`void Update() => rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);`
but it look damn

Comment: @shingo and about `FixedUpdate()` i use it in my char script but all the same

Comment: If the rigidbody is affected by gravity, the vertical velocity always decreases by 9.8 during each physical simulation. If you want it to remain stationary, then you should set `v.y = 9.8f`. And as mentioned above, directly modifying the velocity is incorrect, you should use `AddForce` instead.